# Getting a SyntaxError when trying out "with" in Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

When attempting to open an existing text file (myfile.txt) with "with":

```
with open ('myfile.txt') as my_new_file:
```

I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-263-06288b4ea914>", line 1
with open ('myfile.txt') as my_new_file:
                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

However, I am able to open the file using "open":

```
myfile = open('myfile.txt') 

myfile.read()

'Hello, This is a text file\nThis is the second line\nThis is the third line'
```

Can someone point out what it is that I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could we have what comes after the with statement?

Comment: So, is there any code after the `with` statement...? _Indented_ code?

Comment: can't reproduce. Please post the full code required to produce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alls you need to do is do something after the colon. Finish the thought.

```
$ python -c "with open ('myfile.txt') as my_new_file:"
  File "<string>", line 1
    with open ('myfile.txt') as my_new_file:
                                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing


$ python -c "with open ('myfile.txt') as my_new_file: print(my_new_file.readlines())"
['hey\n', 'you\n']
```

Answer (score 1):

An EOF error is an unexpected **End Of File** error where, the Python interpreter was expecting something part of the `with` statement on the next line.

For example:

```
with open ('myfile.txt') as my_new_file:
    my_new_file.read()
```

is valid.  Since the with statement has something in it, whereas:

```
with open ('myfile.txt') as my_new_file:
my_new_file.read()
```

Will return an error since there is nothing part of the `with`, when there should be at least one function in order to use the flow control.

If you have nothing to do then you should call `pass`.  This has nothing to do with the file you want to read.  Exactly the same effect can be made by using any statement that requires an indent, without the indent:

```
for i in range(100):
print('Hello')
```